# MYSQL wait_timeout and maxlifetime

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-18.04

A few months ago I acquired a VPS and a few days ago I decided to install MYSQL in it, and I am having some errors regarding Minecraft / Spigot plugins that require MYSQL.

The error it gives me in console is the following:

```
[22:41:40 WARN]: [User Authenticator # 2] WARN fr.xephi.authme.libs.com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - AuthMeMYSQLPool - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@58e89c5e ( No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter max Lifetime value.
```

This is something about MYSQL configuration and I do not understand what may be happening, I hope you can guide me or help me, since I have read everywhere and I still cannot solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long did the connection stay up?

Comment: @RickJames It was not even 10 seconds, he sends it to me every so often.